# Excel automatic repeat, convert rows into columns

Tags: excel, automation

I've got 2 worksheets

#### Sheet 1

> This worksheet will contain a single row with each column a different heading in it

[image]

#### Sheet 2

> I want this sheet to automatically populate column A with each of the headings from row 1 in Sheet 1, which would create this

[image]

How would I go about automating this in Excel 2016 e.g When I add a new column in Sheet 1, it adds a new row in Sheet 2?

Thanks

Comment: Select Sheet1!A1:A3, Copy, Select Sheet2!A1, paste-special->Transpose

Comment: copy row 1 paste special transpose in A2, then delete row 1.  If you want vba then record a macro while doing this.

Comment: If i were to add a macro, could i get it to trigger each time a new item gets added to sheet 1?

Comment: Yup, You would then call the recorded macro from a Worksheet_Change event.

Comment: @ScottCraner I dont spose you know of any good beginner articles that explain how to go about that do you?

Comment: The way I learned was google.  Google `Worksheet_Change vba` and you should get a plethora of information.  Then Google `PasteSpecial transpose`

Comment: @ScottCraner is right here. You may get someone posting you an exact code answer but you wouldn't really learn anything to use going forwards. The more you can take existing concepts and apply them to your specific task the better off you'll be for it in future. I'm presuming when you learnt javascript you had to do similar things.

Comment: @TimEdwards sure, This question isn't actually for me, it's to be passed onto somebody who is trying to sort something out in, rather than learning how macros, events work, which is why I asked for any proven useful resources so they could be passed on, rather than me telling them to just google it

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the TRANSPOSE function, though it has a limitation in that you have to plan ahead and know how many rows / columns you expect to have.

Steps:

1. In Sheet Two, select a range of cells in Column A, say the first 10 rows, A1:A10
2. While the cells are highlighted enter this into the formula bar `=TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!A1:J1)` Before leaving the formula bar, hit `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER` (This makes Excel treat it as an Array formula).

Note that the number of columns you select from Sheet1 in the formula must match the number of rows you highlighted in Sheet2 when you were entering the formula. (A to J is ten columns)

Unfortunately, TRANSPOSE returns 0 whenever there is a blank value in the range it's looking at.  A workaround is to use the IF formula to check for 0 and return an empty string instead:

`=IF(TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!A1:J1)=0, "", TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!A1:J1))` and `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`